# Size of with paddding

Tags: c, struct

What is the size (in bytes) for the following structures on a 32­bit machine
installed with the Linux Operating System?

sizeof(int) = 4 bytes 
 
sizeof(short) = 2 bytes
 
sizeof(char) = 1 byte

**1**

```
struct foo {
    int d1;
    char c1;
    int d2;
}
```

**2**

```
struct foo {
    int d1;
    char c1;
    int d2;
    char c2;
    short s;
};
```

**3**

```
struct foo{
    int d1;
    int d2;
    char c1;
    char c2;
    short s;
};
```

**4**

```
struct foo {
    char c1;
    int d1;
    short s;
    int d2;
    char c2;
};
```

ANSWERS: 
 
12,
 
 
16,
 
12,
 
20

Could someone please explain how to find these answers? I am very confused and not understanding the concept here.

Can someone explain the padding requirement for each? That's my confusion. I don't understand whats required.
!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a common duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with alignment of data types, which means that particular data types (e.g. int) may not start at any address but at - let say - only on memory addresses `p % 4 == 0`. This allows the compiler - depending on the architecture - to make use of optimizations often provided by processors for such data types.

It seems that `int` has an alignment of `4`, i.e. it may start only at memory addresses `p % 4 == 0`. So if you have a struct with an `int d1`, then a `char c1` and then an `int  d2`, the compiler needs to introduce 3 padding bytes  after `c1` such that `d2` starts at an address `p % 4 == 0`. That's why.

Datatypes without (or less restrictive) alignment restrictions can be packed without (or with less) padding in between.

The next thing is that objects of such a `struct` "inherit" alignment restrictions in the sense that such an object itself must start at an address such that the alignment restrictions of its members are not violated. That means that if you have a struct with `int`s and alignment `4`,  such a struct-object itself might have trailing padding bytes if otherwise consecutive object would violate alignment. Note that (plain) arrays guarantee to have no padding between the elements of the array, so any padding will have to be part of the structs. This applies to your example no 4, which is therefore of size 20  (and not 17).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For a 32-bit x86 machine, these values are correct:

```
sizeof(int) = 4 bytes
sizeof(short) = 2 bytes
sizeof(char) = 1 byte
```

Here are the values for a 64-bit Linux machine:

```
/*
   EXAMPLE OUTPUT (64-bit Linux):
     sizeof(char)=     1
     sizeof(int)=      4
     sizeof(short)=    2
     sizeof(long)=     8
     sizeof(long long)=8
     sizeof(char *)   =8
 */
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf ("sizeof(char)=%d  \n", (int)sizeof (char));
  printf ("sizeof(int)=%d  \n", (int)sizeof (int));
  printf ("sizeof(short)=%d  \n", (int)sizeof (short));
  printf ("sizeof(long)=%d  \n", (int)sizeof (long));
  printf ("sizeof(long long)=%d  \n", (int)sizeof (long long));
  printf ("sizeof(char *)=%d  \n", (int)sizeof (char *));
  return 0;
}
```

"Padding", however, is implementation dependent:

> https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP03-C.+Do+not+assume+the+size+of+a+structure+is+the+sum+of+the+sizes+of+its+members
>
> Subclause 6.7.2.1 of the C Standard states, "There may be unnamed
>   padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning" [ISO/IEC
>   9899:2011].

Different compilers can "pad" elements in a structure different ways.

One compelling reason for padding is "performance".  For example:

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/structure-member-alignment-padding-and-data-packing/
>
> if the integer is allocated at an address other than multiple of 4, it
>   spans across two rows of the banks as shown in the below figure. Such
>   an integer requires two memory read cycle to fetch the data.
>
> A variable’s data alignment deals with the way the data stored in
>   these banks. For example, the natural alignment of int on 32-bit
>   machine is 4 bytes. When a data type is naturally aligned, the CPU
>   fetches it in minimum read cycles.
>
> Similarly, the natural alignment of short int is 2 bytes...

So in your example, the offsets for fields d1, c1 and d2 would be:

```
offset(foo.d1)=0
offset(foo.c1)=4  <-- This is true for 32-bit or 64-bit x86/x64 CPUs
offset(foo.d2)=8  <-- So is this...
```

The total size would be 4 + 4 + 4 = 12